# Angular Routing and Query String

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, query-string, angular-routing

I don't really know how to put this issue. I don't even know if it is really an issue, please pardon me.

I have two menu link having the same url with a query string value to differentiate what content to load

[image]

A: `Url` `http://localhost:55944/#/listing.html?type=buy`

B: `Url` `http://localhost:55944/#/listing.html?type=rent`

Discovery: When A is clicked the listing page loads with content of type 'buy' and if B is clicked while on the listing page, the page does not reload and content of type 'rent' is not loaded vis a vis.

**Route:**

```
 $stateProviderReference
      .state(routeName, {
          url: url,
          templateUrl: templateUrl,
          data: { pageTitle: pageTitle, layoutId: layoutId },
          controller: controller,
          resolve: {
              deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                  return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                      name: name,
                      insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before a LINK element with this ID. Dynamic CSS files must be loaded between core and theme css files
                      files: files
                  });
              }]
          }
      })
```

Comment: What does your (relevant) routing config for these routes look like?

Comment: I think you should make separate routes without any query param, `http://localhost:55944/#/listing/buy` and `http://localhost:55944/#/listing/rent`

Comment: @devqon I have added the route. I loaded it dynamically. Thanks

Comment: I meant what the `url` of the said routes look like, I cannot see that in this dynamic route code

Comment: you want a dynamic load of css and js files or ? routing is your issue?

Comment: @devqon http://localhost:55944/#/listing.html?type=buy and http://localhost:55944/#/listing.html?type=rent